# Outside the bounds of the array in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having 4 angles that is stored in an array:
`90 180 270 360`
I am using one of these when a trigger gets activated. However I am getting an error saying index was outside the bounds. Why is this happening?

```
public float[] rotateAngles;
int i = 0;

 public void OnTriggerEnter (Collider col) {
        if (!enabled) return;

           Rotate ();
   }

 public void Rotate(){
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, rotateAngles[i], transform.eulerAngles.z);
        i++;

        if(i>rotateAngles.Length){
            i = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if(i==rotateAngles.Length)`

Comment: Thanks. The error thrown is at line `transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, rotateAngles[i], transform.eulerAngles.z);`

Comment: I know, the mistake is this line `if(i>rotateAngles.Length){`

Comment: in general for wrap around while increasing you can simply use `i = (i + 1) % rotateAngles.Length;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because an index starts with 0, and the length starts counting with 1. So if you have an `float[]` with the length 5 your last index of the array is 4.
Just change your if condition to the following:

```
    if (i == rotateAngles.Length - 1) {
        i = 0;
    }
```

And your program should be working fine.